# How does this trick work? bool && printf()

Tags: c, boolean, printf

How does this work?

```
int x = 0;
x && printf("Hello World!");
```

This will output nothing on terminal, but

```
int x = 1;
x && printf("Hello World!");
```

will output "Hello Wolrd!"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How well do you understand `&&`?

Comment: bralebr, Tip: Best to cut and paste true output text than re-type with a transcription error.

Comment: Oh! I get it now. So first the left side of the expression is going to be evaluated, if its false then  there's no need to evaluate the second expression. Therefore, the printf() isn't executed, rigth? @Beta

Comment: That's the [short-circuit rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). When `x == 0` the whole expression must be false without needing to evaluate `printf()`.

Comment: Exactly right. (And you got it before anyone answered!)

Answer (score 2):

It is called short circuit evaluation of a logical expression. Logical expressions are evaluated until the result is undetermined.

In this case:

- if `x==0` logical AND will be `false` despite the other side of the
  expression. `printf` will not be called.
- if `x==1` the result of AND is still undetermined. `printf` will be called.

The result of this AND operation is not used and compiler will warn you.

Comment: It's called short circuit, not short hand. And I think you meant to say "determined" instead of "undetermined" in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard specifies the behavior of `&&` in clause 6.5.13. Paragraph 4 says:

> Unlike the bitwise binary `&` operator, the `&&` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second operands. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.